# how should I prevent the UI from being stuck when unzipping file with ZIP in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to print the progress on unzipping a file on the swiftUI. but each time the UI gets stuck while doing so. I am using [ZIP](https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip) as a 3rd part library.
I tried this code to make unzipping on a different thread

```
    utils.initWindow()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.utils.unzipFile(fileLocation: URL(string: "/Users/user/Downloads/Archive.zip")!, destination: URL(string: "/Users/user/Downloads/testunzip")!)
    }
```

and this is how I implemented the function unzipFile

```
    public func unzipFile(fileLocation: URL, destination: URL){
    self.launcher.addLog(log: "Retrieving files")
    do{
        try Zip.unzipFile(fileLocation, destination: destination, overwrite: true, password: "", progress: { (progress) -> () in
            print(progress)
            self.launcher.setState(state: progress)
        })
    }
    catch {
        self.launcher.setState(state: progress)
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
}
```

PS: `setState` basically sets a value of a `@Published` variable on a `@ObservedObject` that control the `Text` on the UI and it works perfectly fine when I am printing the progress on a different function that prints the progress on downloading a file

Comment: `URL(string:` is the wrong API for file system URLs

Comment: it does unzip the file though! the task is completed successfully but the UI gets stuck and then goes back to normal after it finishes unzipping

Comment: That's because you're doing the unzipping on the main thread. It's a compute intensive operation, so it freezes the UI. You probably want to do something like: `DispatchQueue.global().async `

Comment: I was hoping to keep updating the UI. but thanks for your response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't perform unzip or zip on main thread as it can be a heavy operation. Instead of main thread use

```
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        }
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you! However doesn't meet my needs. the UI isn't getting stuck anymore but the progress isn't being printed on the Text

Comment: All UI changes should be on **main thread**.In your case use  `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` inside `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        }` for updation of UI.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you Raj